# Background colour rotator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js and tween max

What I have: http://jsfiddle.net/hGr4n/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
changeBackground();

TweenMax.delayedCall(0.4, frame01);
});

function changeBackground() {
TweenMax.to('body', 3, {
    backgroundColor: colors[count],
    onComplete: changeBackground,
    ease: Linear.easeNone
});

if (count == colors.length - 1) {
    count = 0;
} else {
    count++;
}  
}
```

I can't get this to work, I know I'm missing something very simple but it should be rotating through the colours.

Comment: TweenMax is undefined in your fiddle.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color#example-use

Comment: I forgot to add in this: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js - here is the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hGr4n/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fiddle the `colors`, the `count` and the `frame01` variables are undefined.

You need to declare them in the apropriate scope(s).

Also, TweenMax is enough for your functional and jquery.colors is not needed.

See the updated [<kbd>**demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/hGr4n/2/)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for your help. I'm still trying to get my head around using prebuilt functions and it's not going too well! Thank you once again.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are using Chrome, use Chrome Developer Tools (***F12***) to catch the errors by yourself

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a lightweight jQuery plugin that is using CSS3 transitions and is perfect for what you're looking for - [ColorRotator.js](https://github.com/askupasoftware/color-rotator)

**Example Usage:**

```
$('#element').colorRotator({
    colors: ['#1abc9c','#16a085','#2ecc71','#27ae60'],
    property: 'background'
});
```

Here are a few [live demos](http://products.askupasoftware.com/color-rotator/)